# Pointer to custom UIView on UITableViewCell returns 0

Tags: objective-c, ios

enter code hereI have a UITableViewCell, to which i have added a custom UIView which is actually a button. I have added the custom UIView programmatically, and set its .tag = 4. The code to draw the button and set the tag is being done in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

I have a function which receives notifications that events have happened, and in this function i am trying to get a pointer to the button in the UITableViewCell so i can change the text on the button, but when i try to retrieve the viewWithTag property, it keeps being returned as 0.

Any ideas?

This is how the button is added to the code:

```
    CustomBadge *customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [plugin items]]<br>withStringColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                                        withInsetColor:[UIColor redColor] 
                                                        withBadgeFrame:YES 
                                                   withBadgeFrameColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                                             withScale:1.0
                                                           withShining:YES];

[customBadge1 setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 80, 10, 30, 25)];
customBadge1.tag = 4;
[cell addSubview:customBadge1];
```

Then in a delegate function, this is how i am trying to get a pointer to the button:

```
CustomBadge* itemBadge = (CustomBadge*) [[[pluginTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]] contentView] viewWithTag:4];
```

Comment: You can try to foreach all the subviews and check for the .tag. Another option is to make a singleton so you always have an pointer to the object. Third option is to post some code here so we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks Melvin. I was going to post code, but i dont have it to hand, its on my Mac which i dont have with me. The singleton is a good idea though!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your tableview allow editing?  At one point I noticed that iOS would assign its own views with low-numbered-tags when you switched into editing mode.  It could be stealing your tag away...  Try a high numbered tag, or use a custom UITableViewCell subclass and get an IBOutlet to the UIView (I always go for this option, it saves a lot of heartache down the line.)

Answer (score 0):

Oh FFS.

I forgot the ".contentview" when i was adding the item to the cell subview.

Thanks to Melvin and jsd for the reponses.